How do I plot an inequality in matplotlib?
I'm trying to plot Tupper's self-referential formula. The formula is:
(1/2) < math.floor(math.floor((y/17)*(2**(-17*math.floor(x)-(math.floor(y) % 17)))) % 2)
As you can see, this inequality contains both x and y, so obviously I cannot plot it normally.
How would I do this? The resulting graph should have large shaded regions instead of just lines.
Thanks!
I tried just matplotlib.pyplot.plot, but that clearly does not work.

Please provide your current code sample of your attempt in using matplotlib.pyplot.plot. Also, for clarity, since this function takes two parameters, simply rename them a and b, and instead assign y to the value of the function, and place this on the y-axis. This way, you can have two x-axis at the top and bottom: each for a and b respectively.

Maybe using sympy with plot_implicit()?

Suggest you add a rough sketch of how you want the plot to look.  "The resulting graph should have large shaded regions instead of just lines." needs clarification

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

N = 4858450636189713423582095962494202044581400587983244549483093085061934704708809928450644769865524364849997247024915119110411605739177407856919754326571855442057210445735883681829823754139634338225199452191651284348332905131193199953502413758765239264874613394906870130562295813219481113685339535565290850023875092856892694555974281546386510730049106723058933586052544096664351265349363643957125565695936815184334857605266940161251266951421550539554519153785457525756590740540157929001765967965480064427829131488548259914721248506352686630476300
H = 17
W = 106


def tupper(x,y):
    return 0.5 < ((y//H) // (2**(H*x + y%H))) % 2

import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
plot.rc('patch', antialiased=False)
for x in range(W):
    for yy in range(H):
        y = N + yy
        if tupper(x,y):
            plot.bar(x, bottom=yy, height=1, width=1, linewidth=0, color='black')

plot.axis('scaled')
buf = 2
plot.xlim((-buf,W+buf))
plot.ylim((-buf,H+buf))
plot.rc('font', size=20)
plot.xticks(range(0, W, 10))
yticks = range(0, H+1, 4)
plot.yticks(yticks, ['N']+['N + %d'%i for i in yticks][1:])
plot.savefig('out.png')

Output:


that doesn't work for me...weird. Thanks anyway though.

@MichaelCarpiano  Writing "that doesn't work for me" isn't very informative.  What exactly doesn't work? Does it crash? Does it generate some different output? Could you edit your post and add the image you got? Are you using the latest library versions? Do you have a 64 bit version of numpy installed? ...?
